# With Chrome Apps going away, what will happen with Postman?

Tags: google-chrome, postman

Apologies if this is not the right place for the question, if it isn't please point me in the right direction.

So Google has just announced that Chrome Apps (packaged or otherwise) are going to be phased out from the Chrome web browser in Windows/Linux/Mac. Where does that leave Postman? I can't find anything addressing this question so far and there doesn't seem to be a standalone web-based or desktop app, at least for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will go away and those users who used Google Chrome App will have to switch to one of the others. They have one for Windows and Mac with Linux coming soon.

https://www.getpostman.com/apps

[image: Postman for Windows]

Comment: Actually they don't have one for Windows currently, they only mention "Chrome", which is actually the packaged app. As far as I know packaged apps are going away as well.

Comment: They do, I have it installed on my Windows Box. Follow the link I provided and you can download it there.

Comment: Also since I have come to understand seeing is believing I have added picture proof to the answer :) Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @makadus - I can understand MorePower's confusion (it was mine as well!), since the other links are quite prominent and the link to the Windows download kinda gets lost in the banner at the top.